# A Related Problem to Erdős' similarity conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory

Erdős' similarity conjecture states that for each infinite set $A\subset \mathbb R$ there is a set $P\subset [0,1]$ of *positive measure* such that for all $t\in \mathbb R$, $\delta\neq 0$ there is some $a\in A$ with $t+\delta a\notin P$. In particular, it is unknown if the sequence $A=\{2^{-n}:n\geq 1\}$ has the property above.

I am considering the following related proposition (not sure if this has been answered in previous literature):

If $E\subset [0,1]$ has *full measure* then there is $t\in \mathbb R$ and $\delta\neq 0$ such that $t+\delta 2^{-n}\in E$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your conjecture is correct. Actually $t$ can be 0.

Comment: @喻良 Thanks! Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Here is the most recent survey: https://www.jstor.org/stable/44153069. Question 1 was answered. I have a positive answer to Question 2 under certain set theoretical assumptions.

Comment: FYI LaTeX-style accenting like `\H{o}` doesn't work in text on this site, only in math.  If you want ő you have to actually type it (if you don't know how to type it on your keyboard, your OS may have a character map tool).

Comment: For $t=0$ almost any $\delta\in (0,1)$ works: not appropriate values are covered by countably many null sets. Well, I guess this may be what 喻 良 essentially says, but without special terminology which I am sorry to be not familiar with.

Comment: @FedorPetrov That is what I meant.  The method can also be used to show that the linear function can be replaced with a ``regular" elementary function ($\sin$, $arcsin$ etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to take this opportunity to give an application of algorithmic randomness theory to this area. Accidentally I am working on the similarity problem recently and found some interesting applications of algorithmic randomness theory to the area.

For the notation of randomness you may refer to the book by Downey-Hirschfeldt or Nies.

> **Proof**: It is simple to see that if $\delta$ is $x$-random, then so is $\delta2^{-n}$ for any $n\geq 1$. But $E$ is conull and so there
>   must be a real $x$ so that every $x$-random belongs to $E$. Then  it
>   is clear that every $x$-random real $\delta$ meets your requirement. QED

Actually this method can be used to prove that   for any countable set $A\subset (0,1)$ , there is a real $\delta$ so that $\delta y\in E$ for any $y\in A$ (The result was proved by Kolountzakis first).

Comment: I am sorry but it has been a almosta year. As I am writing my thesis, would you send me a link to one of your articles available online that proves this fact?

Comment: I have not written it up. I think that the result should be well known. You may just cite the link as many math papers already have done.

Comment: @ 喻 良 Thanks for your reply! But the link you sent me did not prove this fact, and I am not able to find any article online which proves it.

Comment: @ThomasYang You may put the proof in your thesis and cite as a "forklore" result. And you found the proof in mathoverflow.